# using Boolean to represent integers

Tags: c++, boolean

In c++, bool is used to represent Boolean. that is it holds true or false. But in some case we can use bool to represent integers also.
what is the meaning of `bool a=5;` in c++?

Comment: This should be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356726/is-bool-a-basic-datatype-in-c

Comment: The Boolean only holds two values:  `true` or `false`, minimally represented by one bit.  To represent a number, you will need a data type with more bits, as you would need to differentiate between 42, 1, 7, 8, etc.

Answer (score 7):

> *"what is the meaning of `bool a=5;` in c++?"*

It's actually equivalent to writing

```
bool a = (5 != 0);
```

> *"But in some case we can use bool to represent integers also."*

Not really. The `bool` value only *represents* whether the integer used to initialize it was zero (-> `false`) or not (-> `true`).

---

The other way round (as mentioned in [@Daniel Frey's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332082/using-boolean-to-represent-integers/30332119?noredirect=1#comment48759151_30332119)) `false` will be converted back to an integer `0`, and `true` will become `1`.
So the original integer value's (or any other expression results like pointers, besides `nullptr`, or `double` values not exactly [representing `0.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020582/treating-double-variable-as-boolean)) will be lost.

---

**Conclusion**

As mentioned in [LRiO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30332269/1413395), it's not possible to store information other than `false` or `true` in a `bool` variable.

There are guaranteed rules of conversion though (citation from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast)):

> #### The safe bool problem
>
> Until the introduction of explicit conversion functions in C++11, designing a class that should be usable in boolean contexts (e.g. `if(obj) { ... }`) presented a problem: given a user-defined conversion function, such as `T::operator bool() const;`, the implicit conversion sequence allowed one additional standard conversion sequence after that function call, which means the resultant bool could be converted to int, allowing such code as `obj << 1;` or `int i = obj;`.
>
> One early solution for this can be seen in `std::basic_ios`, which defines `operator!` and `operator void*` (until C++11), so that the code such as `if(std::cin) {...}` compiles because `void*` is convertible to `bool`, but `int n = std::cout;` does not compile because `void*` is not convertible to `int`. This still allows nonsense code such as delete `std::cout;` to compile, and many pre-C++11 third party libraries were designed with a more elaborate solution, known as the [Safe Bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool).

Comment: For the last part: A `bool` value does represent `0` or `1` when converted to integer. It just cannot represent any other integer values.

Answer (score 3):

**No, we can't.**

It's just that there's an implicit *conversion* from integer to boolean.

Zero becomes `false`; anything else becomes `true`.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this declaration

```
bool a=5;
```

is equivalent to

```
bool a=true;
```

except that in the first declaration 5 as it is not equal to zero is implicitly converted to `true`.

From the C++ Standard (4.12 Boolean conversions )

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
>   to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to false; any other value is converted to true. For
>   direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

One more funny example

```
bool a = new int;
```

Of course it does not mean that we may use bool to represent pointers. Simply if the allocation is successfull then the returned poimter is not equal to zero and implicitly converted to `true` according to the quote I showed.

Take into account that till now some compilers have a bug and compile this code successfully

```
bool a = nullptr;
```

Though according to the same quote a valid declaration will look like

```
bool a( nullptr );
```

Answer (score 0):

And, basically, I would opine that `bool b=5` is "just plain *wrong.*"

Both C and C++ have a comparatively weak system of typing.  Nevertheless, I'm of the opinion that this should have produced a compile error ... and, if not, certainly a rejected *code review*, because it is (IMHO) more likely to be an unintentional mistake, than to be intention.

You should examine the code to determine whether `b` is or is not "really" being treated as a `bool` value.  Barring some "magic bit-twiddling purpose" (which C/C++ programs sometimes *are* called-upon to do ...), this is probably a typo or a bug.

Vlad's response *(below)* shows what the standard says will happen *if* you do this, but I suggest that, "since it does not make *human-sense* to do this, it's probably an error and should be treated accordingly by the team.

A "(typecast)?" Maybe. A data-type mismatch such as this?  *Nyet.*

Comment: _"And, basically, I would opine that bool b=5 is "just plain wrong.""_ Why actually? It's perfectly valid.

Comment: Because, in my opinion, it is unlikely that a programmer would *intentionally* do that:  specify that a "Boolean" (i.e. "yes-or-no") variable is equal to "5."  Therefore, and whether the language specification stipulates that the compiler is to accept it *(it does ...)*, I would presume that it very likely represents "human error."  In any case, it is a construct that is not intuitively understandable / obvious.  ("If it's 'boolean,' then Which is it? True or False?")  I'd change the code.

Comment: Well, I'm using such stuff in production code (very successfully), e.g. to instantiate certain number of components using a configuration define value, and check if there are any of these components available/enabled.

Comment: _"Vlad's response (below)"_ It's no longer _below_, you should just [link to it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30332149/1413395). Also the point is, that the information if some value was zero or not, can still be useful in a program, and there's no need to bother with _type safety_ for such case. Conversion rules are well defined.

Comment: Uh huh.  Gotcha.  Basically, my comment is that "in production code, stuff easily gets overlooked."  (And, we rely a *lot* on what we see, e.g. in a variable's declared data-type.  On what we *expect* to see.)  If a "Bool" variable actually doesn't contain just "yes/no," then I would like to see "(typecasts)" to better-describe to the (always, harried ...) "gentle reader," what the actual intention is.  Anything that's inconsistent *could* be a bellwether of an as-yet undiscovered mistake.